# Get action parameter on OnActionExecuting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Using .NET core MVC C#

I have a controller as:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyCustomFilter))]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string type)
    {

    }
}
```

In my filter I want to get the string value of `type` as it's being passed as a query string.

And my filter as:

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCustomFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
          //this is always null
           string id = filterContext.RouteData.Values["type"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Anything I am missing here? Because I have read few posts and they have mentioned the above to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For parameters passed in query string use:

```
string id = filterContext.Request.Query["type"];
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Modified as below    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["type"] != null)
                {
                    
                }

Answer (score 5):

I believe you could use something like the following.  I use something similar to the below in a logging filter.  The log filter code is below as well.  You could also iterate the collection as well.

```
string id = filterContext.ActionParameters["Type"];
```

Iterating through all parameters and aggregating them into a log string that is eventually written to a file.

```
logString = filterContext.ActionParameters.Aggregate(logString, (current, p) => current + (p.Key + ": " + p.Value + Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 2):

In .NET Core it's `ActionArguments` now.

```
string type = filterContext.ActionArguments["type"];
```

P.S. I wonder why they keep renaming stuff just for the sake of renaming it. Darn.